# How to Statistics Data in AODV Networks of OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I want to obtain statistics for the following indicators in the AODV example: network entry time, network exit time, packet loss rate, network formation time, latency, throughput, hop count, and other data. What should I do? I studied the OMNeT++simulation manual, but I didn't learn it. I hope to receive everyone's help and express my gratitude here

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "network entry time", "network exit time"? Moreover, are you interested in packet loss rate per every link or for the whole network?

Comment: The network entry time here refers to the time when the route was established, and the network exit time refers to the time when the route failed. Yes, I am very interested in packet loss rate per every link or for the whole network

Comment: In the AODV example provided by OMNeT++, I found that the route from the source node (host [0]) to the destination node (host [1]) is different from the route from host [1] to host [0]. Why is this? I hope to receive your help

Comment: this is my ini code


[Config Test]

description = routing without mobility and 64

sim-time-limit = 100s

*.numHosts = 64

*.host[*].wlan[*].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 3000m

*.host[0].app[0].destAddr = "host[1](ipv4)"

**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 10000m

**.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 10000m

*.host[0].app[0].stopTime = 90s

Comment: I found that as long as metric ≥ 3, there will be inconsistencies between forward and reverse routing. However, this situation does not exist in AODV. So where exactly is the problem